# How can i cancle a 'Precompiled Header' in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c

i tried to create the project in Visual Studio 2022 choosing a DLL project. However, i could not cancle a precompiled header which is cpp file because i wasn't be able to see the option which cancles a precompiled header.

Comment: Should be something like "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers" in Properties.

Comment: You have a project set up for a precompiled header and you want the precompiled header to go away, is that right?